# Create/Update Parent relation when Create/Update child relational model in Yii2

Tags: activerecord, yii2, relationship, updatemodel

I have a **User** model (name, username, password,..) and a **Customer** model which has a relation 1 to 1 with User model, this model is used to store (firstName, lastName, email, ...).

I want to let customers to create their accounts via registration process, where they are asked to provide (First Name, Last Name, email, password, ..)

So, it is clear that the registration process must create a **User** account first (using, First name and last name as Name, email as username, and the password). Then the **Customer** account can be created.

Even though, if the customer wants to change his name later, we must update the the field Name in the User account..

**What is the best way to achieve this in Yii2??**

I tried to override beforeSave() on Customer AR, but the problem i faced is how to populate attributes with the related User while it is not created yet.

**So the problem is: How can we create a User account when creating a new Customer account? And, how to update the related User account when updating the customer account?**

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply manage this in the Customer Controller, with a properly change of create and update action.

eg for actionCreate :

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $modelCustomer = new Customer();
        modelUser = new User(); 


        if ($modelCustomer->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $modelCustomer->save()) {
            modelUser->name = $modelCustomer->name; 
            .........
            $modelUser
            return $this->redirect(['index']);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $modelCustomer,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick replay. But is there a way to do it from the Customer model? This will help to not repeat the process.

Imagine that the customer can register his self and the ADMIN can create/update customers account. In this case we have to maintain the relationship twice.

Comment: And another issue, I can not save Customer model before I save the User model, because the customer table inherits from user table. So, I need to insert a user record in DB and get the id, then i can insert the customer record.